# async or promise all, reject all if first fails - 3 post method calls

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Edited. I need to call `addUser()` to receive the `userId` back thats generated from the database. Then i need to call `addTicket()` with the `userId` to receive the `ticketId` back thats generated from the database. Then finally call `addToBooks` with the `userId` and `ticketId`. These are all post methods, the only data I need back from each call are their `id`s, the last post method will return full data. Is there a way to handle this where I can fail all post methods if any one of the fails in the process? I've seen examples of promise.all that can do this but it was all for get methods.

Comment: `getUser()` will execute because it's the first function call made. Everything will be blocked since you're using `await`, and the it will run the `Promise.all`. Additionally, it seems like you're not using `await Promise.all` which will cause issues if you need the returned value afterward. + you're saying something about `addUser()`, but in your example there is no such thing.

Comment: You mention `addUser`, but it's not included in your code.
Additionally, can you please clarify if you are attempting to run these 3 requests for an array of users?

Comment: What is a "get method" vs a "post method"? What do you want to "fail", and how would it be different than for "get methods"?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, following your functions names example:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const userId = await addUser();
    if(userId) {
       const ticketId = await addTicket(userId);
       const response = await addToBooks(userId, ticketId);
       return response;
    } else {
       throw new Error("Error getting data")
    }
  } catch(error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
}
```

This doesn't use `Promise.all`, but since the example you are giving, to my understanding, only needs the `userId` to complete the other 2 operations, I think this should work

Comment: Why test for the existence of `userId`, but not for existence of `tickedId`? Why catch the error and handle it with a meaningless `console.log`? Just let it propagate